How to get deployment progress in GitHub Actions using arm-deploy action?
Consider the arm-deploy GitHub Action:
https://github.com/Azure/arm-deploy#another-example-on-how-to-use-this-action-to-get-the-output-of-arm-template
Is there any way to get deployment progress, similar to terraform apply, when using this action to deploy a Bicep template?

I only see that it exposes the template outputs as Action output variables:

And we know our Action writes this output(s) to an action output
variable with the same name, we can access it using ${{
steps.deploy.outputs.containerName }} (Note: deploy comes from the id
field from above.)


No, to my best knowledge, The arm-deploy GitHub Action does not provide a built-in way to get deployment progress similar to terraform apply. Let's See if anyone else has another opinion or has figured out if it does.
However, I was able to can pass outputs of arm template deployment as variables, using ${{ steps..outputs. }}, including the provisioningState if included as part of the output of the template.
param topicNameParam string
param tagsParam object = {}
param location string = resourceGroup().location

var serviceName = 'exampleservice'

module eventGridTopic './Modules/eventGridTopic.bicep' = {
  name: '${serviceName}-eventGridTopic'
  params: {
    topicName: topicNameParam
    location: location
    tags: tagsParam
  }
}

output topicProvisioningState string = eventGridTopic.outputs.topicProvisioningState

workflow to print output
    - name: Deploy Bicep file
      id: bicep-deploy
      uses: azure/arm-deploy@v1
      with:
        subscriptionId: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION }}
        resourceGroupName: ${{ secrets.AZURE_RG }}
        template: ./Infrastructure/main.bicep
        parameters: ./Infrastructure/main.bicepparam
        deploymentName: sampleDeployment
        deploymentMode: Complete
        failOnStdErr: false

    - name: Get deployment outputs
      run: |
        echo "Provisioning State: ${{ steps.bicep-deploy.outputs['topicProvisioningState'] }}"


